# Simplifying a logic expression with 3 variables

Tags: boolean-algebra

Below is a problem that I did. I am hoping that somebody can verify that my work is correct or tell me where I went wrong.
Thanks.

---

Problem:
Simplify the following expression using Boolean Algebra:
$$ x = (M + \overline N)(\overline M + P)(\overline N + \overline P) $$
Answer:
\begin{align*}
x &= (M \overline M + \overline N \, \overline M  + MP + \overline N P) (\overline N + \overline P) \\
x &= ( \overline N \, \overline M  + MP + \overline N P) (\overline N + \overline P) \\
x &=  \overline N ( \overline N \, \overline M  + MP + \overline N P) +  \overline P ( \overline N \, \overline M  + MP + \overline N P) \\
x &=  \overline N \, \overline M  + \overline N MP + \overline N P +  \overline P ( \overline N \, \overline M  + MP + \overline N P) \\
x &=  \overline N \, \overline M + \overline N P +  \overline P ( \overline N \, \overline M  + MP + \overline N P) \\
x &=  \overline N \, \overline M + \overline N P +  \overline P \, \overline N \, \overline M  +  \overline P MP +  \overline P \, \overline N P \\
x &=  \overline N \, \overline M + \overline N P +  \overline P MP +  \overline P \, \overline N P \\
x &=  \overline N \, \overline M + \overline N P +  \overline P \, \overline N P \\
x &=  \overline N \, \overline M + \overline N P \\
\end{align*}
Let me call the original expression \$e1\$ and the simplified expression \$e2\$. I want to look at both expressions
for the case of \$M = 1\$ and \$N = 1\$.
\begin{align*}
e1 &= (1 + \overline 1)(\overline 1 + P)(\overline 1 + \overline P) \\
e1 &= (0  + P)(0 + \overline P) = P \overline P \\
e1 &= 0 \\
e2 &= \overline 1 \, \overline 1 + \overline 1 P = 0 + 0P = 0 \\
\end{align*}
Therefore, it checks for this special case. Now I will consider the special case of \$M = 0\$ and \$N = 0\$.
\begin{align*}
e1 &= (0 + \overline 0)(\overline 0 + P)(\overline 0 + \overline P)  \\
e1 &= (1)(1 + P)(1 + \overline P)  = 1 \\
e2 &= \overline 0 \, \overline 0 + \overline 0 P = (1)(1) + 1P \\
e2 &= 1 \\
\end{align*}
Therefore, it checks for this special case.

Comment: I also get \$\overline{N}\left(P+\overline{M}\right)\$.

Comment: Since it is a third question of the series, it looks like you might benefit from the simplest technique of verifying this stuff - a truth table. 3 variables is giving a really short 8-row truth table, so to verify your results you draw one for the original expression and one for the result and compare. Not speaking of online (or off-line) tools for generating these tables from expressions.